# Deleting TTY_00000000.log logs from server

Tags: linux, logging

I have log file named TTY_00000000.log on my server which is of more then 2GB. 
Can anyone let me know whether I can empty this file & how can I stop creation of this huge logs or minimize them in anyway?

Thanks,

Gaurav.

Answer (score 2):

See [this thread](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2008-March/035673.html). Quotes:

> These are a very important debugging tool for the PERC 5 controllers so
>   the ability to disable them is not exposed.
>
> What you need is a simple logrotate script (Dell should have included one). Compression would save almost all the space since they are a lot of repetitive text.

```
cat > /etc/logrotate.d/omsa-tty <<EOF
/var/log/TTY_00000000.log {
    monthly
    notifempty
    rotate 15
    compress
}
EOF
```